# Why does UIButton sometimes lost width constriain?

Tags: ios, uibutton, storyboard

There's a UIButton which does transition between two controllers. Either the two controllers have the same functionality of flipping to each other. It works pretty well, except that "sometimes" the button's width shrinks, while most of the time it looks just normal. The height and width of the button are both set to 35, a baseline constraint with its previous object and a trailing constraint with its `superview` in the storyboard is also declared. The background of the button is assigned to a image set in images.xcassets file. Is there any possible reason that the button width sometimes shrinks?

Normal state of the UIButton

[image: normal state of the UIButton]

And sometimes the UIButton thinks like this

[image: sometimes the UIButton thinks like this]

Comment: How small does it shrink?

Comment: I've already added the images of the abnormal UIButton. It looks like that the whole image is compacted. Just cannot figure out why and under what condition would this happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the image is making space for title. This may be the case if you're using a standard UIButton. Try setting it to a custom type then you will have more control over the survives it contains.

Comment: The button is set to "Custom" of its type. However, since you had mentioned about the space of button title, I found that the button had a default title. When I remove the default title text in the storyboard, the problem seems to be solved. Thanks a lot for your answer!